# An efficient way to find the row number of a data frame, unequal condition

Tags: r, search, indexing

We are looking at a delay of a server that can only take care of one customer simultaneously. Let's say we have two data frames: `agg_data` and `ind_data`.

```
> agg_data
  minute service_minute
1      0    1
2     60    3
3    120    2
4    180    3
5    240    2
6    300    4
```

`agg_data` provides service time between two successive customers for every **hour**. For instance, between 60 and 120 (the second hour from the beginning), we can serve a new customer every 3 minutes and we can in total serve 20 customers for that given hour.

`ind_data` provides arrival minutes of each customer:

```
         Arrival
1             51
2             63
3            120
4            121
5            125
6            129
```

I need to generates the departure minutes for the customers, which are affected by the `service_minute` in the `agg_data`.

The output looks like:

```
         Arrival              Dep
1             51               52
2             63               66
3            120              122
4            121              124
5            125              127
6            129              131
```

Here is my current code, which is correct but very inefficient:

```
ind_data$Dep = rep(0,now(ind_data))
# After the service time, the first customer can leave the system with no delay
# Service time is taken as that of the hour when the customer arrives
ind_data$Dep[1] = ind_data$Arrival[1] + agg_data[max(which(agg_data$minute<=ind_data$Arrival[1])),'service_minute']

# For customers after the first one, 
# if they arrive when there is no delay (arrival time > departure time of the previous customer), 
# then the service time is that of the hour when the arrive and 
# departure time is arrival time + service time; 
# if they arrive when there is delay (arrival time < departure time of the previous customer), 
# then the service time is that of the hour when the previous customer leaves the system and 
# the departure time is the departure time of the previous customer + service time.

for (i in 2:nrow(ind_data)){
ind_data$Dep[i] = max(
ind_data$Dep[i-1] + agg_data[max(which(agg_data$minute<=ind_data$Dep[i-1])),'service_minute'],
ind_data$Arrival[i] + agg_data[max(which(agg_data$minute<=ind_data$Arrival[i])),'service_minute']
                )
}
```

I think it is the step where we search for the right service time to use in `agg_data` takes long. Is there a more efficient algorithm?

Thank you.

Comment: what happens if 20 or more arrivals occur between 60-120?

Comment: The same to what happens to the 4th and 5th customers. There will be a queue (delay). The customers will be served according to the sequence of arrival. The starting time of service is the maximum of the arrival time of the customer and the departure time of the previous customer. The service time of this customer is the service time at the starting time.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly efficient. It's a very simple lookup problem with an obvious vectorized solution:

```
out <- data.frame(Arrival = ind_data$Arrival,
         Dep = ind_data$Arrival + agg_data$service_minute[ # need an index to choose min
                              findInterval(ind_data$Arrival, agg_data$minute)] 
 )

> out
  Arrival Dep
1      51  52
2      63  66
3     120 122
4     121 123
5     125 127
6     129 131
```

I trust my code more than your example. I think there are obvious errors in it.

Comment: The output is wrong. For the 4th customer, departure time should be 124 but not 123. Customer 3 leaves the system at 122 and the serve can start to take care of customer 4 at 122. The service time between 120 and 180 is 2 minutes, so customer 4 leaves at 124. The system cannot take care of customer 4 when it arrives at 121 because it is taking care of customer 4.

Comment: OK, that should be possible to fix with a call to `max` (and it's possible that a for-loop would be the best strategy), but what about the 5th and 6th customers? How are you judging efficiency?

Comment: The same logic applies to the 5th and 6th customers. The departure times are as in the question post (I made a mistake on the departure times of these two customers and I have edited my post. Maybe the mistake confused you in the first place. Sorry about that.) By efficiency, I mean computation time.